# RabbitMQ Failed to initialize erlang distribution

Tags: cmd, erlang, rabbitmq, windows-10

I have installed RabbitMQ but when I try to use `rabbitmqctl status` in cmd I have next result:

```
D:\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-3.6.2\sbin>rabbitmqctl status
Error: Failed to initialize erlang distribution: {{shutdown, {failed_to_start_child, net_kernel, {'EXIT',nodistribution}}}, {child,undefined, net_sup_dynamic, {erl_distribution, start_link, [['rabbitmq-cli-70', shortnames]]}, permanent,1000,supervisor, [erl_distribution]}}.
```

Folder with Erlang : D:\erl7.3

I have following environment variables : 
ERLANG_HOME : D:\erl7.3 
ERLANG_SERVICE_MANAGER_PATH : D:\erl7.3\erts-7.3\bin

How can I fix this to RabbitMQ install correctly?

Additionally: I've done all steps from this tutorial [programmershandbook.wordpress.com/2015/03/22/rabbitmq-setup](http://programmershandbook.wordpress.com/2015/03/22/rabbitmq-setup) but when I try work with `cmd` i have the same error.

And `erl_crush.dump` have following first strings:

```
=erl_crash_dump:0.3
Fri May 20 12:29:12 2016
Slogan: Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{k
System version: Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10]
Compiled: Mon Mar 14 21:51:02 2016
Taints: 
Atoms: 4811
Calling Thread: scheduler:3
```

It can be connected with using Windows 10 or something else?

Comment: In general this means that the node couldn't connect to the `epmd` daemon, which probably wasn't started because of some reason. Try `epmd -names`. If it doesn't work try to start it with `epmd -daemon`. Then `epmd -names` again. This later command should show the node running once it has been started. Also see this: http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2013-May/027322.html

Comment: Are you running it with admin rights? I had a similar error when enabling the rabbitmq management plugin on ubuntu, but it all worked well when I did a `sudo` to get superuser rights. Could be something similar on windows (maybe try to run the cmd window as administrator).

Comment: Try uninstalling / reinstalling the service, worked for me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258392/rabbitmq-has-nodedown-error

Answer (score 35):

Running the command with sudo worked for me

```
 » sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management                                                  
The following plugins have been enabled:
  mochiweb
  webmachine
  rabbitmq_web_dispatch
  amqp_client
  rabbitmq_management_agent
  rabbitmq_management
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I'm so happy I googled this before trying to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Me too! :D Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks @Dr Manhattan. Having the exact same issue the TS had (`Failed to initialize erlang distribution...`) while trying to enable rabbitmq_management using `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`. The `sudo` saves my life.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this error running the same command with sudo permission

Comment: What does this add that the top rated answer missed?

Answer (score 0):

It is very abstract error and many misconfigurations may lead to this. Have you tried to set also `NODE_NAME` to something like `bunny@localhost`?

Comment: `NODE_NAME` is setted to `rabbit@%COMPUTERNAME%`.