# Create vHost on Windows RabbitMQ node using command line

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I have a RabbitMQ node on windows operating system. I want to create vhost on that node from command line of using a script with minimal pre-requisites.

EDIT: I tried to use the rabbitmqctl add_vhost but I always get an error.

[image]

Answer (score 26):

```
rabbitmqctl add_vhost my_vhost
```

and

```
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p my_vhost guest ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

I suggest to read this: https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html

So you have another error, about the node down read here
[RabbitMQ has Nodedown Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258392/rabbitmq-has-nodedown-error)

Comment: I tried the first command but each time I use the add_vhost I get an error. Edited the question.