# RabbitMQ node authentification failed after changing cookie file

Tags: windows, cookies, server, rabbitmq, messaging

I have multiple RabbitMQ nodes running on different machines. After installing each node I failed to specify a common cookie for each of them to use so I had to go back and manually change the file .erlang.cookie . My issue is that after doing this I get conflicting error messages. If i do rabbitmqctl status 
I get the following error:

> ## DIAGNOSTICS
>
> attempted to contact: ['rabbit@nc-mso-test01']
>
> rabbit@nc-mso-test01:   * connected to epmd (port 4369) on
>   nc-mso-test01   * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672   *
>   TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
>
> - Authentication failed (rejected by the remote node), please check
>     the Erlang cookie
>
> current node details:
>   - node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-45@nc-mso-test01'
>   - home dir: C:\Users\jol
>   - cookie hash: 9/Hx6l+wLQv3NkmSDFqBog==

Whatever script I call, I get the same error. I tried restarting the service, removing and installing it through rabbitmq-service. The error persists. From what I can gather from other posts, the reason might be that the node and the erlang broker are running on separate users and each of them have a different version of the cookie, one is stuck with the old one.

How can I make the server and node restart, so that both of them use the new cookie file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I solved my issue. I missed the fact that the RabbitMQ setup has two cookie files, one in c:\Windows for the erlang component, and one in C:\Users\%USER%. From what I understand, if the erlan VM is started on it's own application user and the RabbitMQ node is started on a different user, which would have been my case, then the two cookie files were different and I had to sync those up before syncing the cluster cookies.

Comment: To eliminate the 50/50 chance... To sync: copy the C:\Windows cookie to overwrite the C:\Users\%USER% cookie

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html, the issue is also described here, with the path for the two cookies given .

Comment: @William Yea, the bottom advice I reached when anyone asks me about rabbitmq is "Read the documentation at least 3 times". All the issues I have had with it, I found the solution just by carefully re reading the documentation.

Comment: Helped me too.
RabbitMQ server restart was needed after sync cookies (if it's not obvious).

Answer (score 6):

Documentation says:

> The cookie file used by the Windows service account and the user running CLI tools must be synchronised. [RabbitMQ-Clustering Guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#erlang-cookie)

On Erlang versions starting with 20.2, the cookie file locations are:

- For user running CLI tools - usually `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.erlang.cookie` for user `%USERNAME%`
- For the RabbitMQ Windows service - `%USERPROFILE%\.erlang.cookie`
  (usually `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile`)

On Erlang versions prior to 20.2 (e.g. 19.3 or 20.1), the cookie file locations are:

- For user running CLI tools - usually `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.erlang.cookie` for user `%USERNAME%`
- For the RabbitMQ Windows service - `%WINDIR%\.erlang.cookie` (usually `C:\Windows\.erlang.cookie`)