# Cannot start rabbitmq, 'node down' Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: rabbitmq

Similar to [RabbitMQ has Nodedown Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258392/rabbitmq-has-nodedown-error). But, this is for Ubuntu 16.04 the working solution, posted below, differs from the windows one as well.

Something has gone wrong with my rabbitmq server. Trying to start the application gives an error:

```
$sudo rabbitmqctl start_app

Starting node rabbit@daniel ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@daniel: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@daniel]

rabbit@daniel:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on daniel
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on daniel
  * suggestion: start the node

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-6647@daniel'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: T1R4ztWXXH1w2IQe+fui9g==
```

Currently the only way I know of solving this is uninstalling/reinstalling rabbitmq. But, I'm hoping a more sensible solution is possible...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RabbitMQ has Nodedown Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258392/rabbitmq-has-nodedown-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the important part of that message:

```
node 'rabbit' not running at all
```

You need to start RabbitMQ with `systemctl start rabbitmq-server`. You should also check the logs to see why it wasn't running in the first place.

Comment: Well. The error shows up because the above command fails. Ironic

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it with `sudo rabbitmq-server`