# rabbitmqctl start_app error on os x: unable to connect to node rabbit@localhost: nodedown

Tags: macos, rabbitmq

I installed rabbitmq server on OS X using the command `brew install rabbitmq`.
When I run `rabbitmqctl start_app` I get the following error

```
Starting node rabbit@localhost ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@localhost: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@localhost]

rabbit@localhost:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on localhost
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  other nodes on localhost: ['rabbitmq-cli-50']
  * suggestion: start the node

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-50@MacAir'
- home dir: /Users/abeer
- cookie hash: S1lhU2Pz5rrKNRd+lGv1og==
```

What exactly is the problem here and how do I remove it?

Comment: `rabbitmqctl start_app` it is not the way to start rabbitmq. look inside `/usr/local/sbin` you should have `rabbitmq-server`

Comment: I want to run it in background. I tried `brew services start rabbitmq` but it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

> The server can then be started with rabbitmq-server. [[Source]](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-homebrew.html)

As I understand from comments you need to run RMQ in background. In order to do that you can just

```
sudo ./rabbitmq-server &
```

Answer (score 1):

run

```
rabbitmqctl reset
```

then

```
rabbitmqctl start
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sudo`

> sudo rabbitmq-server start

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue in my remote-server, because I use the command to set the hostname:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname controller
```

But the command line header still is `localhost`:

```
[root@localhost ~]#
```

So, I exit the remote-server, then re-connect it, I can use `rabbitmq-server` now.